# NUllPointerException element webdriver

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, webdriver

```
public WebElement waitFindElement(By by) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5000);
    wait.until( ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(by));
    return driver.findElement(by);
}

public void clickOrigem() {
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    WebElement opcaoOrigem = util.waitFindElement(By.xpath(".//*[text()='Sua   empresa']")); 
    openSite.highlightElement(opcaoOrigem);
    opcaoOrigem.click();    
}

public void clickSubMenuContas() {
    pagPrincipal.clickOrigem();
}
```

I can't find the element, it gives `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below xpath

```
//*[text()[contains(.,'Sua   empresa')]]
```

Also Check the number of spaces between the two words.